# Have java classes all inherit from another Object. (Between Object and Class)

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm not sure how to get the first part going  which is inheritance.
I know in java all classes inherit from the Object class. I want to have all classes  in Java **also** inherit from my own custom base class. Something like this:
ObjectClass>CustomBaseClass>OtherClasses

I'm wondering is this possible to do in java without having to ship a custom JRE? I'm needing to augment alot of java classes to contain some extra fields.

Comment: That is not possible.  But this sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) - what are these augmented fields you need?

Comment: Tags. Certain classes such as GUI and Nodes needs to have the abilities to hold certain tags. Therefor when you're iterating over an object you're able to take  specific actions based on the tags of the class. (For example all menu items that need to be enabled only when a file is loaded could have a certain tag.)

Comment: Try some smalltalk :)

Comment: What is smalltalk? +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most definitely ***cannot*** *insert* a superclass into the hierarchy. What would it mean to insert your base between `Object` and `String`, this would not be meaningful.

I agree, this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

There's nothing stopping you from setting up your own class hierarchy to include the common base class everywhere for your own classes, but even that can lead to design headaches since Java doesn't support multiple inheritance.

Comment: What resources would you suggest if I'm trying to manage states of menu's and other components dynamically, based on user actions  (file loaded, file deleted, new file)? Without hardcoding each possible state in.(Which takes alot of time and is messy.)

Comment: You haven't explained your requirements clearly enough (i.e. with a concrete example that demonstrates exactly what you are trying to do) for us to really understand your objective and why you think inserting into the middle of the class hierarchy is a solution.  I suggest you come up with a [mcve] of what you need and asking a new question.